# The process cannot access the file when using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, file

Basically I want to create a file if not existing then write message to it.

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
    File.Create(filePath + fileName);
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(filePath + fileName,false);
```

How to deal with this error?

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\blahblah' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`File.Create` opens a `FileStream` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx).

As you didn't dispose it, the file remains locked and subsequent accesses to the file will fail because of this situation if these are performed from other handles (i.e. other `FileStream` or the whole `StreamWriter`).

This code demonstrates how you should work with `IDisposable` objects like `FileStream`:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
{
    File.Create(filePath + fileName).Dispose();

    using(StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(filePath + fileName,false))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with File.Create then?  Just pass the path to the file to the constructor of the StreamWriter and avoid creating the extra object that you don't use.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yeah, absolutely, but I was answering to "why the second part can't access the file?". You know.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the `StreamWriter` constructor that takes in the file name?

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(filePath + fileName);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx):

> The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share. **If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.**

Very minor point but you could consider using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) when concatenating file names and folder paths.

Comment: Do I have to create it first and make sure it exists or not?

Comment: Did you read the quote? `If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, **a new file is created**.`

Answer (score 3):

Simplify your code by using single method to create and open a file:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path)) 
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true)
                         .GetBytes("This is to test the OpenWrite method.");

    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

MSDN: ([File.OpenWrite Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

> Opens an existing file or creates a new file for writing.